# Setting variables in logstash config and referencing them

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I started ELK a week back to use it for storing multiple CSVs and getting them to kibana for ease of analysing them. One case will involve multiple machines and one machine will generate many CSVs. Now these CSVs have a particular naming pattern. I am taking one particular file ( BrowsingHistoryView_DMZ-machine1.csv ) for reference and setting up the case as index. To define an index I've chosen to rename files to have prefix of '__case_number __' . So the file name will be- 
*__1__BrowsingHistoryView_DMZ-machine1.csv*

Now I want to derive two things out of it.
1. Get the case number __1 __ and use 1 as index. 1 , 2 , 3 etc will be used as a case numbers.

2. Get the filetype (BrowsingHistoryView for ex.) and add a tag name to the uploaded file.

3. Get the machine name *DMZ-machine1* (don't know yet where I'll use it).

I created a config file for it, which is as below-

```
    file {
        path => "/home/kriss/Documents/*.csv"  # get the files from Documents
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        }
        if [path] =~ "BrowsingHistory" { mutate { add_tag => ["Browsinghistory"] }    # define a new tag for browser history, this worked
            grok {  match =>    ["path", "__(?<case>[0-9]+)__(?<category>\w+_)(?<machine>(.+)).csv"]     # This regex pattern is to get category(browsingHistory), MachineName
            }           
        }
        if [path] =~ "Inbound_RDP_Events" { mutate { add_tag => {"Artifact" => "RDP" } } }          
        }  # This tagging worked

output {
        elasticsearch  {
            hosts => "localhost"
            index => "%{category}"  # This referencing the category variable didn't work
        }
    
stdout {}
}
```

When I run this config on logstash, the index generated is **%category** . I needed it to capture browser_history for the index of that file. Also if I can convert the category to small  letters, since sometimes uppercases don't work well in index. 
 I tried to follow the official documentation but didn't get the complete info that I need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a grok debugger in Dev Tools in Kibana you can use to work on these kinds of problems, or an online one at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ - it's great.

Below is a slightly modified version of your config. I've removed your comments and inserted my own.

The changes are:

- The `path` regex in your config doesn't match the example filename you gave. You might want to change it back, depending on how accurate your example was.
- The `grok` pattern has been tweaked
- Changed your `Artifact` tag to a field, because it looks like you're trying to create a field

I tried to stick to your spacing convention :)

```rb
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/kriss/Documents/*.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        }
        # I replaced your  regex with something matches your example 
        # filename, but given that you said you already had this
        # working, you might want to change it back.
        if [path] =~ "browser_history" {
            mutate { add_tag => ["Browsinghistory"] }
            grok {
                # I replaced custom captures with a more grokish style, and
                # use GREEDYDATA to capture everything up to the last '_'
                match => [ "path", "^_+%{NUMBER:case}_+%{GREEDYDATA:category}_+%{DATA:case}\.csv$" ]
            }           
        }
        # Replaced `add_tag` with `add_field` so that the syntax makes sense
        if [path] =~ "Inbound_RDP_Events" { mutate { add_field => {"Artifact" => "RDP" } } }
        # Added the `mutate` filter's `lowercase` function for "category"
        mutate {
            lowercase => "category"
        }
    }

output {
        elasticsearch  {
            hosts => "localhost"
            index => "%{category}"
        }
    
stdout {}
}
```

Not tested, but I hope it gives you enough clues.

Comment: Thanks for the update @tomr. I tested it but the variable value isn't getting passed to index over here- __index => "%{category}"__     
Is there any way to check it all verbosely when this logfile gets applied to logstash?

Comment: Sorry for the misconfiguration. I realised now that I was passing wrong data to GROK. The value of path was never that I wanted it to carry. So I placed the literal value of a filename and variable value got passed to index in output section.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the reference for anyone who is trying to use custom variables in logstash config file. Below is the working config-

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/home/user1/Documents/__1__BrowsingHistoryView_DMZ-machine1.csv"   # Getting the absolte path (necessary)
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
filter {
        csv {
                separator => ","
                }
                if [path] =~ "BrowsingHistory" { mutate { add_field => {"artifact" => "Browsinghistory"} }     # if BrowsingHistory is found in path, add a tag called Browsinghistory
                        grok {  match => ["path", "__(?<case>[0-9]+)__(?<category>\w+_)(?<machine>(.+)).csv"]    # get the caseNumber, logCategory, machineName into variables
                        }
                }
                if [path] =~ "Inbound_RDP_Events" { mutate { add_field => {"artifact" => "RDP"} } }     # another tag if RDP event file found in path
                }

output {
                elasticsearch  {
                        hosts => "localhost"
                        index => "%{case}"          # passing the variable value derived from regex
                        # index => "%{category}"    # another regex variable
                        # index => "%{machine}"     # another regex variable
                }

stdout {}
}
```

I wasn't very sure whether to add a new tag or a new field (**add_field => {"artifact" => "Browsinghistory"}**) for easy identification of a file in kibana. If someone could provide some info on how to chose one out of them.